# Chinnmasta/Chinnmastika Clarification

Tags: devi, shakti, shaktism, dasha-mahavidya, chinnamasta

A number of the sites I’m perusing say Chinnamasta is originally a Buddhist goddess who was later over centuries incorporated into the Hindu pantheon. A number of religious scholar types asserting this in books and whatnot (They get so much stuff wrong though)

Anyway isn’t it the other way round ? Isn’t Chinnmasta originally a Hindu goddess part of the Dus MahaVidya 10 Wisdom Goddess ? As part of Shakta sect of Hinduism ? And then later became part of Buddhist system. Wouldn’t there be scriptural proof of this ?

Seems like a lot of stuff is taken and then claimed as being their own from the start when that’s not the case. But I’m not hundred percent sure. Wondering if you guys could clarify. Thx

(I’m posting too many questions but this was bothering me for long time. Thx for any info)

Comment: Worship and Deities present in Tantra texts are meant to be kept secret which is why we do not see any text from very ancient time. Since the time Buddhism came into existence, they slowly took many tantric deities and rituals into Buddhist mainstream and they start spreading it as if it is their own. Since for Hindus, the rules were important, they did not until recent time from Abhinavagupta Bhashkara Shankaracharya etc. Many of these started composing the texts on the rituals and deities.

Comment: Thx ! Ok so that’s why it happened the way it did. Was wondering what is up with these huge amounts of misleading erroneous info promulgated by so many “scholars” In their lectures, books. Have realized many misguided notions are out there concerning Tantric goddesses. Thx for clarifying